# Reading csv files with pyarrow types with dask

Tags: dask, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am trying to read a csv file, with column dtypes specified as pyarrow data types, `pa.DataType`. The following example doesn't seem to work, even though I specified the dtype and engine as pyarrow:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pyarrow as pa

pa_types = {'A': pa.string(), 'B': pa.float64()}
file_path = './test.csv'

df = dd.read_csv(urlpath=file_path, sep=';', dtype=pa_types, engine='pyarrow', dtype_backend='pyarrow')
df = df.sort_values('A')
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False, single_file=True, sep=';')
```

test.csv:

```
A;B
2;1
4;2
0;5
```

I can do a workaround by defining a mapping from `pa` types to `np` types but I was wondering if there's a built in way of doing this since we're explicitly specifying pyarrow in params.

```
pyarrow==14.0.2
dask==2023.12.1
```

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: `KeyError: DataType(uint32)`